# Как убрать заглушку писем на denwer

Tags: denwer

У denwer при отправке письма с php скрипта функцией `mail()` письма складываются в папку `\WebServers\tmp\!sendmail` и не отправляются.

Как убрать заглушку чтобы письма отравлялись на email?

Comment: поставь `openserver` и не парься))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рискну описать:

Вам понадобиться архив рабочего `sendmail`, скачать можно попробовать [тут](http://ektcs.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/sendmail.rar).

Далее будьте внимательны, размещение очень важно, так как папок `bin` с разным размещением на Денвере много, но вот правильная папка, которая наша, одна:
`\WebServers\usr\bin`. Вот эта папка нужна на денвере, папок `bin`, ради интереса гляньте, на Денвере целая куча, и так закинули распакованный архив куда надо.

После разархивации у вас получиться вот такая картинка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настраиваем нужные файлы:

- **php.ini** по адресу `\WebServers\usr\local\php5` в разделе `[mail_function]`
  В этом разделе надо бы закоментить с помощью `;` все данные которые в нем были, оставил включенным только `mail.add_x_header = On`, также прописать путь к новому файлу `sendmail.ini` добавив следующую строчку, `sendmail_path = \usr\bin\sendmail -t` .

Для наглядности пишу ниже как получается:

```
; For Win32 only.  
; http://php.net/smtp  
;SMTP =  
; http://php.net/smtp-port  
;smtp_port = 25  

; For Win32 only.  
; http://php.net/sendmail-from  
;sendmail_from =  

; For Unix only. You may supply arguments as well (default: «sendmail -t -i»).  
; http://php.net/sendmail-path  
;sendmail_path = \usr\sbin\sendmail -t -i  
sendmail_path = \usr\bin\sendmail -t  

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters  
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of  
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.  
;mail.force_extra_parameters =  

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename  
mail.add_x_header = On  

; The path to a log file that will log all mail() calls. Log entries include  
; the full path of the script, line number, To address and headers.  
;mail.log =
```

- **sendmail.ini** по адресу `\WebServers\usr\bin`

В этом файле надо заполнить свои данные по используемому вами почтовому ящику.
Например у нас почта на `gmail.com`. Настройки получаются

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=25
smtp_ssl=auto
error_logfile=error.log
auth_username=myLoginOnGmail@gmail.com
auth_password=lSD45gh4e
force_sender=myLoginOnGmail@gmail.com
force_recipient=
hostname=gmail.com
```

Для наглядности тоже выкладываю код файла все данные которые прописаны в нем:

```
; configuration for fake sendmail  

; if this file doesn’t exist, sendmail.exe will look for the settings in  
; the registry, under HKLM\Software\Sendmail  

[sendmail]  

; you must change mail.mydomain.com to your smtp server,  
; or to IIS’s «pickup» directory. (generally C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Pickup)  
; emails delivered via IIS’s pickup directory cause sendmail to  
; run quicker, but you won’t get error messages back to the calling  
; application.  

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com  

; smtp port (normally 25)  

smtp_port=25  

; SMTPS (SSL) support  
; auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS  
; ssl = alway use SSL  
; tls = always use TLS  
; none = never try to use SSL  

smtp_ssl=auto  

; the default domain for this server will be read from the registry  
; this will be appended to email addresses when one isn’t provided  
; if you want to override the value in the registry, uncomment and modify  

;default_domain=mydomain.com  

; log smtp errors to error.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)  
; uncomment to enable logging  

error_logfile=error.log  

; create debug log as debug.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)  
; uncomment to enable debugging  

;debug_logfile=debug.log  

; if your smtp server requires authentication, modify the following two lines  

auth_username=my_ya@gmail.com  
auth_password=lSD45gh4e  

; if your smtp server uses pop3 before smtp authentication, modify the  
; following three lines. do not enable unless it is required.  

;pop3_server=  
;pop3_username=  
;pop3_password=  

; force the sender to always be the following email address  
; this will only affect the «MAIL FROM» command, it won’t modify  
; the «From: » header of the message content  

force_sender=my_ya@gmail.com  

; force the sender to always be the following email address  
; this will only affect the «RCTP TO» command, it won’t modify  
; the «To: » header of the message content  

force_recipient=  

; sendmail will use your hostname and your default_domain in the ehlo/helo  
; smtp greeting. you can manually set the ehlo/helo name if required  

hostname=gmail.com
```

Но на `windows` лично я бы рекомендовал `openServer`. У него можно настроить всё что душе угодно, любые версии `php, database`, почту и прочее

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Немного по мучавшись по инструкции сделал, тк чет не сразу заработало...